# SyntaxError: C:\dev\portafolio-frontend\src\components\CardProject.js: Missing semicolon (18:21)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Buenas y gracias de antemano,no se porqué al querer implementar un background-image me sale un mensaje de error SyntaxError: C:\dev\portafolio-frontend\src\components\CardProject.js: Missing semicolon (18:21).
Dejo mi codigo , estoy usando style components [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]y material UI. Muchas gracias

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. Español, es mejor agregar el código de lo que has intentado, en vez de imágenes [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conozco mucho sobre los `styled-components`, pero sospecho que tu problema debe tener que ver con las comillas invertidas de JavaScript  ``.

Creo que las estás volviendo a abrir innecesariamente y eso crea el error de sintaxis.

Quizás deberías probar escribirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
background-image: url(${ImageFondo});
```

Sin las comillas invertidas en la parte del `background-image`.

Pienso que ese debe ser el problema por lo que vi aquí: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3238

En ese ejemplo no se usan las comillas invertidas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era ello. A pesar de haberlo googleado no encontraba solucion :D .

Comment: Genial. No olvides marcar una respuesta como "aceptada" si realmente te fue útil, [aquí se explica cómo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas)